# Droppable - hoverClass

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using the jquery ui droppable and draggable.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GykzX/)

When I drag the Container 4 to a droppable div (.container)  the hoverClass works as excepted - the background will be blue if is a drop zone.

However when I drag the Container 3 (with the Container 4 inside) the hoverClass doesn't work - the background is always red, but if I drop in red zone, the drop is accepted.

<del>### EDIT: ###
**This works in Chrome!  Firefox and IE doesn't work!**</del>

#### EDIT 2:

**The issue happens when try to drag an inner container first (with out drop). After that the hover class doesn't apply**

So what must I do to activate the hoverClass when I have a drag with drag and drop?

Thanks  in advance!

Html:

```
<div class=drag>
<div>Container-1</div>
<div class=container>
    <div class=drag>
        <div>Container-2</div>
        <div class=container>
            <div class=drag>
                <div>Container-3</div>
                <div class=container>
                    <div class=drag>
                        <div>Container-4</div>
                        <div class=container></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.drag {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:white;
}
.container {
    margin-left:30px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:red
}

.drag + .drag{
    margin-top:10px
}

.drop-area{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        revert: true,
        opacity:0.9,
        start: function(){
            $(this).attr("oldZIndex",$(this).css("z-index"));
            $(this).css("z-index", 3000);
        },
        stop:function(){
            $(this).css("z-index", $(this).attr('oldZIndex'));
        }
        /*helper: "clone"*/
    });
    $(".container").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log($(this), ui.draggable);
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        },
        hoverClass: 'drop-area',
        greedy: true,
        tolerance: "pointer"
    })
```

Comment: just tested on IE11 and FF30, works like a charm. What kinds of version you tested on?

Comment: I use IE11 and FF30 too. When I drag the container3 to drop in container1, the container 1 never gets blue, is always red (the hoverClass is not applied). But if you drap the container4 to drop in container1, the container 1 gets blue (the hoverClass is applied)

Comment: well, again I've just tested it, works like a charm. Not sure what's  happening on your side.

Comment: snapshot here http://i.imgur.com/k5GKu0z.png

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I only notice now! The hoverClass works if you try directly move the container3 to container1. However, if you try to drag the container4 (with out drop anywhere) and try after move the container3 to 1 the hover class doesn't work.

Comment: snapshot here [http://imgur.com/TLEOfF8](http://imgur.com/TLEOfF8) Thanks for help King King

Comment: now I can reproduce the problem however it happens to all browsers, not just FireFox and IE. So there is something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am still looking into this. But an intermediate solution is the below code. I have added the active-class setting to the droppable event.

```
$(".drag").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        revert: true,
        opacity:0.9,
        start: function(){
            $(this).attr("oldZIndex",$(this).css("z-index"));
            $(this).css("z-index", 3000);            
        },
        stop:function(){
            $(this).css("z-index", $(this).attr('oldZIndex'));
        }
       /* helper: "clone"*/
    });
    $(".container").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log($(this), ui.draggable);
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);           
        },
        hoverClass: 'drop-area',
        activeClass: 'drop-area',
        greedy: true,        
        tolerance: "pointer"



    })
```

But the issue still remains is that when the outer div is being dragged, then the greedy setting is not working for the 3rd container. Will update the same once I can fix the greedy issue.